# Name Error - name api is not defined

Tags: python-3.4, tweepy

I am trying to extract tweets from twitter within certain time frame. code

```
import tweepy
import csv
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

#csvFile=open('tweets.csv','a')
#csvWriter=csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="#tatamotors",
                           lang="en",
                           since="2016-01-12",
                           until="2016-06-07").items():

    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    #csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at,tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

i am getting - "name error: name api is not defined"

Comment: Where did you expect it to come from?

Comment: ok i got it , corrected

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a line before the call of `api`, construct the `api` first using this:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Comment: after editing i am getting tweets but now facing unicode encode error

Comment: Try this: `print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: getting a letter 'b'before every tweets such as "b Nos JLR has been a winner last 5 months consecutive !'"

Comment: how to get location for each tweets .